# Can I use two where clauses, like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something and something"?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with my products and I'm trying to write a page that would pull bracelets with certain colors from the database. So here's what I have right now (in php):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE (products.colors LIKE '%black%')";
```

But I only want to select rows where the value for the column "category" equals "bracelet".

I've tried a few different things, but I keep getting warnings and errors. I appreciate any help you can give, thank you!

Comment: You can combine conditions using `AND` or `OR`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.colors LIKE '%black%' AND products.category = 'bracelet'";
```

There you go.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple, but for some reason I couldn't find it with all my mad Googling.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE colors LIKE '%black%' 
AND category = 'bracelet'
```